# Kubernetes pod failing with Invalid Volume Zone mismatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, persistent-volumes

I have a jenkins service deployed in EKS v 1.16 using helm chart. The PV and PVC had been accidentally deleted so I have recreated the PV and PVC as follows:

Pv.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: jenkins-vol
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  awsElasticBlockStore:
    fsType: ext4
    volumeID: aws://us-east-2b/vol-xxxxxxxx
  capacity:
    storage: 120Gi
  claimRef:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    name: jenkins-ci
    namespace: ci
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: gp2
  volumeMode: Filesystem
status:
  phase: Bound
```

PVC.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: jenkins-ci
  namespace: ci
spec:
  storageClassName: gp2
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 120Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  volumeName: jenkins-vol
status:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 120Gi
  phase: Bound
```

kubectl describe sc gp2

```
Name:            gp2
IsDefaultClass:  Yes
Annotations:     kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"storage.k8s.io/v1","kind":"StorageClass","metadata":{"annotations":{"storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"true"},"name":"gp2","namespace":""},"parameters":{"fsType":"ext4","type":"gp2"},"provisioner":"kubernetes.io/aws-ebs"}
,storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class=true
Provisioner:           kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
Parameters:            fsType=ext4,type=gp2
AllowVolumeExpansion:  True
MountOptions:          <none>
ReclaimPolicy:         Delete
VolumeBindingMode:     Immediate
Events:                <none>
```

The issue I'm facing is that the pod is not running when its scheduled on a node in a different availability zone than the EBS volume? How can I fix this

Answer (score 1):

Add a nodeSelector to your deployment file, which will match it to a node in the needed availability zone (in your case us-east-2b):

```
  nodeSelector:
    topology.kubernetes.io/zone: us-east-2b
```

Comment: added the node selector and now the pod is in pending state with

0/5 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient CPU, 5 node(s) didn't match node selector even though I have two instances in us-east-2b

Comment: do a kubect describe node <your-node> and get all the node annotations

Answer (score 1):

Add following labels to the PersistentVolume.

```
  labels:
    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region: us-east-2b
    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone: us-east-2b
```

example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  annotations:
    pv.beta.kubernetes.io/gid: "1000"
  labels:
    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region: us-east-2b
    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone: us-east-2b
  name: test-pv-1
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  csi:
    driver: ebs.csi.aws.com
    fsType: xfs
    volumeHandle: vol-0d075fdaa123cd0e
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  volumeMode: Filesystem
```

With the above labels the pod will automatically run in the same AZ where the volume is.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Persistent volume documentation kubernetes default scheduler will use the nodeAffinity information from the PV definition.

> nodeAffinity defines constraints that limit what nodes this volume can be accessed from. This field influences the scheduling of pods that use this volume.

[Link to doc](https://v1-24.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/config-and-storage-resources/persistent-volume-v1/#PersistentVolumeSpec:%7E:text=nodeAffinity%20defines%20constraints%20that%20limit%20what%20nodes%20this%20volume%20can%20be%20accessed%20from.%20This%20field%20influences%20the%20scheduling%20of%20pods%20that%20use%20this%20volume.)

That means you will have to ensure the PV definition looks as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pvc-name
spec:
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: topology.ebs.csi.aws.com/zone
          operator: In
          values:
          - ap-south-1a
...
```

Generally this should get auto populated but if this is missing then thats what causing the scheduler to schedule pod on node where the volume can not be attached.

The label mentioned here comes from the one of the node label.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Node
metadata:
  labels:
    ...
    topology.ebs.csi.aws.com/zone: ap-south-1a
    topology.kubernetes.io/region: ap-south-1
    topology.kubernetes.io/zone: ap-south-1a
```

Hope, this help someone.