# Kubernetes PVC error - Cannot bind to requested volume : storageClassName does not match

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-pvc

I have a EKS cluster in AWS, which I manage using `eksctl` and `kubectl` in EC2. I am trying to create a persistent volume to bind it to multiple pods. I have created an EBS volume (gp2, 5GB) in region `us-east-1` for this purpose. My manifests are like below;

### storage-class.yml

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: ebsgp2
parameters:
  fsType: ext4
  type: gp2
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
reclaimPolicy: Retain
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
allowedTopologies:
- matchLabelExpressions:
  - key: topology.kubernetes.io/region
    values:
    - us-east-1
  - key: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
    values:
    - us-east-1a
    - us-east-1b
    - us-east-1c
```

### pv.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: aws-pv
  labels:
    topology.kubernetes.io/region: us-east-1
    topology.kubernetes.io/zone: us-east-1a
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  csi:
    driver: ebs.csi.aws.com
    fsType: ext4
    volumeHandle: vol-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

### pvc.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: ebs-claim
  namespace: namespace1
  labels:
    topology.kubernetes.io/region: us-east-1
    topology.kubernetes.io/zone: us-east-1a
spec:
  volumeName: aws-pv
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: ebsgp2
```

I requested the persistent volume claim using the command;

```
kubectl apply -f pvc.yaml
```

Then I listed PV and PVC with the commands below;

```
kubectl get pv
kubectl get pvc -n namespace1
```

PV got created;

```
NAME     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM   STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
aws-pv   5Gi        RWO            Retain           Available                                   27m
```

And I could see the status of PVC as pending;

```
NAME        STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
ebs-claim   Pending   aws-pv   0                         ebsgp2         20s
```

`kubectl get sc` showed below output;

```
NAME            PROVISIONER             RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE      ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
ebsgp2          kubernetes.io/aws-ebs   Retain          WaitForFirstConsumer   true                   8m53s
gp2 (default)   kubernetes.io/aws-ebs   Delete          WaitForFirstConsumer   false                  3h23m
```

To investigate, I described the PVC using command `kubectl describe pvc -n namespace1 ebs-claim` and found the output like below;

```
kubectl describe pvc -n namespace1 ebs-claim
Name:          ebs-claim
Namespace:     namespace1
StorageClass:  ebsgp2
Status:        Pending
Volume:        aws-pv
Labels:        topology.kubernetes.io/region=us-east-1
               topology.kubernetes.io/zone=us-east-1a
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      0
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                 From                         Message
  ----     ------          ----                ----                         -------
  Warning  VolumeMismatch  30s (x62 over 15m)  persistentvolume-controller  Cannot bind to requested volume "aws-pv": storageClassName does not match
```

Could somebody please tell me why its is happening? Thank you.

Reference;

- https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/tree/master/examples/kubernetes/dynamic-provisioning/manifests
- [Kubernetes Pod Warning: 1 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51946393/)
- [Kubernetes pod failing with Invalid Volume Zone mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69546663/)

Comment: please show the output of `kubectl get sc`

Comment: @TheFool added the same to question, thanks.

Comment: @Alfred have you created Storage class before you apply Persistent Volume Claim?

Comment: @RichardRublev yes, before I applied PVC. Thanks.

Comment: By the looks of it, you are using [Dynamic provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/) which means you don't actually need to create a PV object. Skip the PV and try using storage class and PVC only instead.

Comment: Alternatively, the PV which is bound to a PVC both need to use the same `StorageClass`, currently you haven't defined a storage class with the PV

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 'storageClassName' under 'spec' for 'PV' as well.  If you don't specify your 'storageClassName', it will use default which is probably the reason why you are having this issue since PV and PVC 'storageClassName' does not match.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#reserving-a-persistentvolume